# Using gomake/gotest for a package with external dependencies

Tags: go, packaging

I have the following package Makefile:

```
include ${GOROOT}/src/Make.inc

TARG=gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/mux

GOFILES=\
        doc.go\
        mux.go\

DEPS=\
        gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/context

include ${GOROOT}/src/Make.pkg
```

I changed TARG and DEPS today to point to the Google code repository as shown above, following [this advice](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/msg/eb62eea97a57c60c).

The problem is: I can goinstall the package and it will install the dependency, but I cannot use gotest or gomake anymore; I get the following error (using Go r59):

```
moraes@yukon:~/dev/repos/gorilla/gorilla/mux$ gotest
rm -f _test/gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/mux.a
make -C gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/context install
make: *** gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/context: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/context.make] Error 2
gotest: "/home/moraes/dev/repos/go/go.r59/bin/gomake testpackage GOTESTFILES=mux_test.go" failed: exit status 2
```

I tried goinstalling the dependency first (`goinstall gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/context`), and it installs correctly in $GOROOT/pkg but the same error occurs with gotest/gomake.

I think I'm missing something pretty basic. How should I proceed to use gomake/gotest with the Makefile above? Is this supposed to work at all, or should I use a different one for development?

Comment: How do you run tests? I just tried it and tests still don't work (with errors in question)...

Comment: Before running the tests, I currently change the Makefile to use relative paths for gorilla packages, e.g., `../context`.

Answer (score 1):

goinstall doesn't use the Makefile at all. Instead, it will parse dependencies directly from your .go files.

To specify dependencies, [annotate your import lines](http://golang.org/cmd/goinstall/) with a "normalised" reference to the dependency. eg.

```
import (
  gorilla_context "gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/context"
...
```

gomake doesn't automatically resolve dependencies though, so you'll have to manually install them.

Similarly, for installing cgo source with goinstall, you can specify CFLAGS and LDFLAGS in comment directives. eg.

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq
#include <zmq.h>
*/
import "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Makefile is trying to find the file gorilla.googlecode.com/hg/gorilla/context in the current directory. Also, why would you want to specify it in a make file as opposed to importing it from within the Source?